# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDTStorage", referenced from:

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, firebase, xcode9.2

I keep getting this warning while trying to build my app, also can't link to firebase. I am using xcode 9.2

```
'''Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v3", referenced from:
      -[APMSqliteStore prepareSQL:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_645df61703f07a6639f4b1de4d0cf5c3.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDTStorage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTUploadPackage.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTLifecycle.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTUploadCoordinator.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTTransformer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'''[1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions like this are incredibly hard to answer because we don't know the scope of your project or what else is involved. It's a good idea to include your podfile and some details about what other things may be causing the issue. There's nothing in the question directly related to Firebase so it's not clear why that tag was added. what does 'link to firebase' mean? Can you update your question with more information?

Answer (score 0):

Add `libsqlite3.tbd` to 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' in the project properties.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that if you're just adding Firebase to a project, sounds like there may be more to the question.